# How can I fully reassign an instance of a class to another instance of that same class (then delete the original object) in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance, operator-overloading

I'm messing around with C++ by making a console game. I have a superclass called "WeaponType." Within this class is a static method that creates all of the types of weapons that I'll need. The child class "Weapon" will inherit from WeaponType. (I'm new to inheritance, so forgive my ignorance in advance.)

The way I see the code now, I'll have to declare a new instance of the WeaponType superclass every time I create an instance of the Weapon subclass. This is a problem because I don't want to create any more instances of the WeaponType superclass that are all initialized on the HEAP in the static method that creates them.

I'm either looking for a way to delete every new instance of the WeaponType superclass after doing what I need to with the object. (For example, if make another instance of WeaponType that specifies it's supposed to be the "melee" object and I have already created an instance called "melee", I want to be able to "migrate" the WeaponType to the original object and delete the new object).

The code I have is not complete, but you should be able to get the idea of what I want.

Here's most of the code for WeaponType:

```cpp
<!-- WeaponType.h -->
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

class WeaponType
{
private:
    static std::map<int, WeaponType*> weapTypeAddresses;

    /* Private setters */
    static void setWeapTypeAddresses(const std::vector<WeaponType*>&);

protected:
    double reloadSpeed;
    int weapTypeID, ammoPerShot, maxAmmo;
    std::string weapTypeName;

public:
    /* Constructors */
    WeaponType(int, double, int, int);
    WeaponType(int);
    WeaponType();
    static void MakeWeaponTypes();

    /* Destructor */
    ~WeaponType();

    /* Converters */
    static int convTo_WeapTypeID(const std::string&);

    /* Getters */
    double getReloadSpeed() const;
    int getWeapTypeID() const;
    int getAmmoPerShot()const;
    int getMaxAmmo() const; 
    std::string getWeapTypeName() const;
    static WeaponType* getWeapTypeAddress(int);
};
```

```cpp
<!-- WeaponType.cpp -->
#include "WeaponType.h"

/* Global Variables */
enum WeaponClasses {
    meleeE, pistolE, machineGunE, shotgunE, sniperRifleE, explosiveE,
    WeaponClasses_SizeE = explosiveE + 1
};

std::vector<std::string> weaponClassNames = 
    { "melee", "pistol", "machineGun", "shotgun", "sniperRifle", "explosive" };

enum reloadSpeeds
{
    meleeRS = 0, pistolRS = 2, machineGunRS = 6,
    shotgunRS = 5, sniperRifleRS = 7, explosiveRS = 30
};

enum ammoPerShots 
{
    meleeAPS = 0, pistolAPS = 1, machineGunAPS = 4,
    shotgunAPS = 2, sniperRifleAPS = 1, explosiveAPS = 1
};

enum maxAmmo
{
    meleeMA = 1, pistolMA = 15, machineGunMA = 50,
    shotgunMA = 20, sniperRifleMA = 10, explosiveMA = 3
};

bool weaponsMade = false;


/*******************
 * Private Setters *
 *******************/

// Maps weapTypeID to its pointer
void WeaponType::setWeapTypeAddresses (const std::vector<WeaponType*>& weapTypePtrs)
{
    weapTypeAddresses[meleeE]       = weapTypePtrs[meleeE];
    weapTypeAddresses[pistolE]      = weapTypePtrs[pistolE];
    weapTypeAddresses[shotgunE]     = weapTypePtrs[shotgunE];
    weapTypeAddresses[machineGunE]  = weapTypePtrs[machineGunE];
    weapTypeAddresses[sniperRifleE] = weapTypePtrs[sniperRifleE];
    weapTypeAddresses[explosiveE]   = weapTypePtrs[explosiveE];
}


/****************
 * Constructors *
 ****************/

WeaponType::WeaponType
    (int weapTypeID, double reloadSpeed, int ammoPerShot, int maxAmmo) :
    reloadSpeed(reloadSpeed), ammoPerShot(ammoPerShot), maxAmmo(maxAmmo)
{
    // Makes sure weapTypeID is a valid int within WeaponClasses
    try
    {
        if (weapTypeID >= 0 && weapTypeID < WeaponClasses_SizeE) { this->weapTypeID = weapTypeID; }
        else { throw weapTypeID; }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cerr << weapTypeID << " is not a valid weapTypeID" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Setting weapTypeID to 0" << std::endl;
        this->weapTypeID = meleeE;
    }

    weapTypeName = weaponClassNames[weapTypeID];
}

/* This is the important constructor that needs to delete the object
that it's constructing */
WeaponType::WeaponType(int weapClassID)
{
    try
    {
        // I need to delete the object that's being created somewhere in here
        switch (weapClassID)
        {
        case meleeE:
            *this = *WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(meleeE);
            break;

        case pistolE:
            *this = *WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(pistolE);
            break;

        case machineGunE:
            *this = *WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(machineGunE);
            break;

        case shotgunE:
            *this = *WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(shotgunE);
            break;

        case sniperRifleE:
            *this = *WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(sniperRifleE);
            break;

        case explosiveE:
            *this = *WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(explosiveE);
            break;

        default:
            throw weapClassID;
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cerr
            << '\"' << e << "\" is not a valid "
            << "weapClassID in WeaponType::WeapType(int)"
            << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Calling destructor" << std::endl;
        delete this;
    }
}

// Empty constructor for reasignment
WeaponType::WeaponType() {}

void WeaponType::MakeWeaponTypes()
{
    if (!weaponsMade)
    {
        WeaponType * melee       = new WeaponType( meleeE,       meleeRS,       meleeAPS,       meleeMA       ),
                   * pistol      = new WeaponType( pistolE,      pistolRS,      pistolAPS,      pistolMA      ),
                   * machineGun  = new WeaponType( machineGunE,  machineGunRS,  machineGunAPS,  machineGunMA  ),
                   * shotgun     = new WeaponType( shotgunE,     shotgunRS,     shotgunAPS,     shotgunMA     ),
                   * sniperRifle = new WeaponType( sniperRifleE, sniperRifleRS, sniperRifleAPS, sniperRifleMA ),
                   * explosive   = new WeaponType( explosiveE,   explosiveRS,   explosiveAPS,   explosiveMA   );

        // Sets all the pointers to weapTypeAddresses map
        std::vector<WeaponType*> weapTypePtrs =
        {
            melee,   pistol,      machineGun,
            shotgun, sniperRifle, explosive
        };
        WeaponType::setWeapTypeAddresses(weapTypePtrs);

        weaponsMade = true;
    }
}


/*****************
 * Other Methods *
 *****************/

/* Destructor */
WeaponType::~WeaponType()
{
    std::cout << "WeaponTypeID \"" << this->weapTypeID << "\" is being deleted" << std::endl;
}

/**************
 * Converters *
 **************/

// Converts weapTypeName to weapTypeID
int WeaponType::convTo_WeapTypeID(const std::string& className)
{
    WeaponClasses weapClass;

    // Makes sure className is valid
    try
    {
        int errorCounter = 0, errorMax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < WeaponClasses_SizeE; i++)
        {
            if (className != weaponClassNames[i]) { errorCounter++; }
            errorMax++;  // Always increases errorMax by 1
        }

        if (errorCounter == errorMax) { throw 0; }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cerr << "className parameter is invalid" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Returning \"" << weaponClassNames[0] << "\"" << std::endl;
        return meleeE;
    }

    // Maps the weapTypeName to weapTypeID
    std::map<std::string, WeaponClasses> Weap_ID;
        Weap_ID[weaponClassNames[meleeE]]       = meleeE;
        Weap_ID[weaponClassNames[pistolE]]      = pistolE;
        Weap_ID[weaponClassNames[machineGunE]]  = machineGunE;
        Weap_ID[weaponClassNames[shotgunE]]     = shotgunE;
        Weap_ID[weaponClassNames[sniperRifleE]] = sniperRifleE;
        Weap_ID[weaponClassNames[explosiveE]]   = explosiveE;

    weapClass = Weap_ID[className];
    return weapClass;
}


/***********
 * Getters *
 ***********/

double WeaponType::getReloadSpeed() const { return reloadSpeed; }
int WeaponType::getWeapTypeID() const { return weapTypeID; }
int WeaponType::getAmmoPerShot() const { return ammoPerShot; }
int WeaponType::getMaxAmmo() const { return maxAmmo; }
std::string WeaponType::getWeapTypeName() const { return weapTypeName; }
WeaponType* WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(int weapClassID)
{
    // Makes sure weapClassID is valid input
    try
    {
        switch (weapClassID)
        {
        case 0:
            break;

        case 1:
            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        default:
            throw weapClassID;
        }
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cerr 
            << '\"' << e << "\" is not a valid "
            << "weapClassID in WeaponType::getWeapTypeAddress(int)" 
            << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Returning " << weapTypeAddresses[meleeE] << std::endl;
        return weapTypeAddresses[meleeE];
    }

    return weapTypeAddresses[weapClassID];
}
```

From Weapon.cpp (not yet created), I'd have something like the following:
(Again, please keep in mind I'm new to inheritance and may have incorrect code.)

```cpp
<!-- Pre-file of Weapon.cpp -->
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "WeaponType.h"

Weapon::Weapon(std::string weapName, double damage, int ammo, int weapTypeID) : 
    WeaponType::WeaponType(weapTypeID)
{
    this->damage = damage;
    this->ammo = ammo;
}
```

And, finally, a bare-bones main method

```cs
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include "WeaponType.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string gunName = "pistolGun";
    double gunDamage = 10.0;
    int gunAmmo = 20;
    int weapTypeID = 1; 

    // Creates a pistolGun object.
    Weapon pistolGun (gunGame, gunDamage, gunAmmo, weapTypeID);

    // The goal is to get the WeaponType* of pistolGun to equal &pistol from WeaponType.
    // That would mean these who lines of code output the same address.
    // Also note: I know this code to reference these addresses is incorrect
    cout << "Address of WeaponType attributes of pistolGun: " << &pistolGun.WeaponTypeAttribs << endl;
    cout << "Address of pistol WeaponType: " &pistol << endl;
}
```

Comment: Generally, prefer composition over inheritance. In this case, that means Weapon shouldn't be inheriting from WeaponType. WeaponType should be a member of Weapon. I'd probably make it a pointer or reference to the WeaponType instance, since it'll be shared amongst all Weapon instances.

Comment: @Ayjay Could you write a few lines of code to give an example of this or provide a link (or both haha)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you're using WeaponType to store all the characteristics, whereas a Weapon represents an actual object in the game, so it has a type but it also has things like ammo or a position in the world and things like this.

Instead of modelling this relationship as Weapon is-a WeaponType, consider modelling it as a Weapon has-a WeaponType. Cutting down your linked code to something reasonable, an approach like this might be better:

```
#include<string>
#include<memory>

class WeaponType
{
public:
    double reloadSpeed;
    int weapTypeID, ammoPerShot, maxAmmo;
    std::string weapTypeName;
};

class Weapon
{
public:
    explicit Weapon(std::shared_ptr<const WeaponType> type)
        : type(std::move(type))
    {
        ammo = this->type->maxAmmo;
    }

    const std::shared_ptr<const WeaponType> type;
    int ammo;
};

int main()
{
    // make the weapon types
    auto pistolType     = std::make_shared<WeaponType>(WeaponType{ 1.0, 0, 1, 20, "pistol" });
    auto machineGunType = std::make_shared<WeaponType>(WeaponType{ 5.0, 1, 1, 100, "machine gun" });
    // ...etc

    // Create some actual weapon objects out of those types
    auto pistolGun1 = Weapon{ pistolType };
    auto pistolGun2 = Weapon{ pistolType };

    auto machineGun1 = Weapon{ machineGunType };
    auto machineGun2 = Weapon{ machineGunType };
}
```